# VLC doesn't play mp4v video converted with VLC to h264/h265

Tags: mp4, video-recording, h.264, vlc, h265

VLC reports the original video as:

```
Codec: MPEG-4 Video (mp4v)
Video resolution: 8192x8192
Frame rate: 7.549296
```

I am using the Convert / Save option to convert the video using the following profile:

```
Encapsulation: MP4/MOV
Video Codec: H-265 (also tried H-264)
Bitrate / Quality: Not Used (18 in h264)
Frame Rate: Same as source
Custom options: crf=18
```

Specifying the quality in the Quality input only works for h264, hence the custom options with `crf=18`.

After converting the video shows fine on YouTube and in PowerDVD but NOT in VLC! When playing the video the stream is reported as:

Codec: H264 - MPEG-AVC (part 10)(avc 1)

The rest, like resolution and frame rate, are as of the original video.

When the video is being played the Statistics window shows that video frames are being decoded but Displayed remains 0. Why would VLC be able to decode the video but not display any frames?

I tried different settings for Hardware-accelerated decoding but it didn't help. I have other videos which report the same codec H264 - MPEG-AVC (part 10)(avc 1) but they are usually using mkv encapsulation rather than mp4 (and upon further inspection, some other details in the codec metadata).

This is MediaInfo for the original video:

```
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : MPEG-4 Visual
Codec ID                                 : mp4v-20
Duration                                 : 1 min 11 s
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Bit rate                                 : 45.2 Mb/s
Maximum bit rate                         : 85.9 Mb/s
Width                                    : 8 192 pixels
Height                                   : 8 192 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 1.000
Frame rate mode                          : Variable
Frame rate                               : 7.549 FPS
Minimum frame rate                       : 3.429 FPS
Maximum frame rate                       : 24.000 FPS
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.089
Stream size                              : 383 MiB (100%)
```

This is MediaInfo for the converted video:

```
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : Baseline@L6.2
Format settings                          : 1 Ref Frames
Format settings, CABAC                   : No
Format settings, Reference frames        : 1 frame
Codec ID                                 : avc1
Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                                 : 1 min 10 s
Bit rate                                 : 114 Mb/s
Width                                    : 8 192 pixels
Height                                   : 8 192 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 1.000
Frame rate mode                          : Variable
Frame rate                               : 7.544 FPS
Minimum frame rate                       : 3.428 FPS
Maximum frame rate                       : 24.006 FPS
Original frame rate                      : 7.549 FPS
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.225
Stream size                              : 978 MiB (100%)
Writing library                          : x264 core 155
Encoding settings                        : cabac=0 / ref=1 / deblock=0:-1:-1 / analyse=0:0x11 / me=dia / subme=0 / psy=1 / psy_rd=1.00:0.15 / mixed_ref=0 / me_range=16 / chroma_me=1 / trellis=1 / 8x8dct=0 / cqm=0 / deadzone=21,11 / fast_pskip=1 / chroma_qp_offset=-1 / threads=24 / lookahead_threads=4 / sliced_threads=0 / nr=0 / decimate=1 / interlaced=0 / bluray_compat=0 / constrained_intra=0 / bframes=0 / weightp=0 / keyint=250 / keyint_min=7 / scenecut=0 / intra_refresh=0 / rc=crf / mbtree=0 / crf=18.0 / qcomp=0.60 / qpmin=10 / qpmax=51 / qpstep=4 / ip_ratio=1.40 / aq=0
Language                                 : English
Codec configuration box                  : avcC
```

I noticed that for the original video VLC shows

```
Decoded format: Planar 4:2:0 YUV
```

even though it's missing in the MediaInfo data for that file. But VLC shows it as empty:

```
Decoded format:
```

in the converted file, even though MediaInfo shows:

```
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
```

Not sure if the addition of Decoded format after conversion would prevent VLC from playing the video, but the fact that VLC cannot play back the video which it produced is highly suspicious. Any ideas?